# Deploy lambda layer and lambda function at the same time to maintain them synchronized

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I have...

- Lambda layer that will be used across many other services (common-layer)
- Lambda functions for `users/orders/payments/etc`

```
services/layers/common-layer
services/[users,orders/payments/etc]/**
```

In order to deploy stuff we need to go to the common-layer, hit `serverless deploy`, and then go to the other services and hit `serverless deploy` as well. If we continue doing this, we cannot achieve synchronized data.

Within the common-layer I have a super important function that needs to be always synchronized with other lambda functions.

```js
// services/layers/common-layer
function getSuperDuperHyperImportantNumber() {
  return 1;
}

// services/[users/orders/payments]
import { getSuperDuperHyperImportantNumber } from 'common-layer'
```

Later, specifications changed... Now we need rename the function to getCoolNumber and return `2` instead of `1`

```js
// services/layers/common-layer
function getCoolNumber() {
  return 2;
}

// services/[users/orders/payments]
import { getCoolNumber } from 'common-layer'
```

- So, how can I deploy these changes simultaneously to maintain lambdas services and the common-layer synchronized?
- Will [serverless-compose](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/compose) help?

Notes:

- Within the lambda services I'm using [a serverless plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-latest-layer-version) to always point at the latest version of mentioned common-layer
- This problem seems the same as the migrations stuff within databases-code

Answer (score 0):

You could add the lambda layer to your serverless deployment. When you run 'sls deploy', it should deploy the layer, then deploy the lambda function with the latest Lambda Layer version attached. Here's a reference template that works this way. The Lambda Layer is specified at the 'provider' level which will apply to all lambda functions in the same file.

https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-add-lambda-layer-to-lambda-function